# center rendered label in High Charts

Tags: css, highcharts

My graph looks like this:

[image]

with plot lines on the x-axis as shown (just after 1993 and 2001) respectively.  I need to get  the lines of the label to be centered both between the two plot lines and with respect to each other.  I started by making a hidden series that corresponded to the plot lines, then using those points to place the label:

```
function(chart){

        var labelOnePos = chart.series[2].data[0],
            text1 = chart.renderer.text(
                'line #1<br>line2 different length',
                labelOnePos.plotX,
                labelOnePos.plotY + chart.plotTop - 300
            ).css({
                color: 'white',
            }).add(),
            box1 = text1.getBBox();
```

but I can't figure out how to align the text.

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/q8ef9mmk/

Comment: Provide a live sample? By the way, is this being done with R?

Comment: I'll work on making a fiddle, but no, not in R.

Comment: You have errors in your fiddle. And I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me; what problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To align text, use `attr({ align: 'center' })`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8ef9mmk/4/

However, when you want to render anything in dimensions of the chart, then remember that plotting area is translated by `chart.plotTop` and `chart.plotLeft`.

And code:

```
var labelOnePos = chart.series[1].data[0],
    text1 = chart.renderer.text(
        'line1<br>a line of diff length',
    labelOnePos.plotX + chart.plotLeft, // add chart.plotLeft!
    150).attr({
        zIndex: 55,
        align: 'center' // center label
    }).css({
        fontSize: sectionLabelFontSize,
        color: 'blue'
    }).add(),
    box1 = text1.getBBox();
});
```

**Extra:**  
You  have wrong order of files, proper order is:

- load jQuery or standalone adapter for Highcharts
- load Highcharts
- load extra plugins for Highcharts

**Extra2:** 
You can consider using [`Axis.toPixels(value, paneCoords)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels) method instead of dummy series.

Comment: Ugh--I feel like I tried every combination and placement of align: center except for that very obvious one.  Is it in the docs somewhere I missed?  I feel like the docs frequently say "supports a limited set of html" without telling you what.  I might be missing it.

Comment: With your comment about the order of files:  does that make a difference in how my program runs, or is it just best practice?

Comment: Yes, that makes huge difference. You shouldn't load plugin for Highcharts before Highcharts - your page won't work in the most cases (see comments under your question..). Regarding API, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.attr) - `align` comes from SVG support.